# What is the application event that is ran when an application is loaded after clicking on a push notification

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

Does anyone happen to know what Nativescript event is fired when the user clicks on a push notification thus opening the app.

In my app it’s always taking me back to the login view even if the user is already authenticated, but only when opening a notification. If I just minimize the app (Android) and then click on the app icon it takes me to the last view.

I have a token that I store following a successful login and check for it on `application.start()` but that doesn't seem to be called when opening the app from a notification.

EX:

app.js

```
var application = require("application");
var Navigator = require("./shared/navigator.js");

application.start({
    moduleName: Navigator.startingPage()
});
```

navigator.js

```
// bunch of stuff before this code
Navigator.prototype.startingPage = function(){        
    return userToken.token ? "views/connections/connection-list" : "views/auth/login";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the app singleTask/SingleInstance.

Comment: Do you mean set the navigator to a single instance or the userToken?

Comment: the token should already be a singleton and maintain state through out the apps lifetime.

Comment: What I mean is to alter the AndroidManifest.xml file and set the main activity  to `singleTask`

Comment: Ah - What does that do, I'm not familiar with that?